# Copying & pasting files from one folder to another and renaming them with a random non-duplicating number

Tags: ios, bash, applescript

I'm an Apple script scrub, but what I am trying to do is have my script copy files from one folder to another and in the process assign it a random non-duplicate number that is not in chronological order.

Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    set destFolder to (make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"NEW BATCH"})
    
    set sourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please select the source images folder")
    
    set numFiles to (number of files of folder sourceFolder)
    
    repeat with i from 1 to numFiles
        
        set newFile to (duplicate some file of folder sourceFolder to destFolder)
        
        set name of newFile to (i & ".jpg" as text)
        
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

I am able to get the copy and pasting as well as assigning it a number, but it comes out as chronologically. Not sure how to get it to get a random number as well as not having it repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Of course *it comes out as chronologically* because you are using a consecutive loop  .

First you have to create a list with the index numbers. To avoid duplicate index numbers get a random **integer** with `some integer` and set the item at the given index to `missing value`

```
tell application "Finder"
    set destFolder to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"NEW BATCH"}
    set sourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select the source images folder"
    set numFiles to number of files of folder sourceFolder
end tell

set indexNumbers to {}

repeat with i from 1 to numFiles
    set end of indexNumbers to i
end repeat

repeat numFiles times
    set randomIndex to some integer of indexNumbers
    set item randomIndex of indexNumbers to missing value
    tell application "Finder"
        set newFile to (duplicate file randomIndex of folder sourceFolder to destFolder)
        set fileExtension to name extension of newFile
        set name of newFile to ((randomIndex as text) & "." & fileExtension)
    end tell
end repeat
```